# Get external player URL from Vimeo api for tvOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, tvos, vimeo-api, vimeo-ios

I want to use vimeo to host videos for a AppleTV app. I realise I will need a pro account to do exactly what I want, but at the moment just trying to do a POC.
What I need to achieve is to retrieve a url of my private video that expires after 1 hour, and I want the app to be authenticated with my credentials, not having the user have to sign in (as if the have the app, then they can view the videos).

Code that I am using is below, the constants set are:

kVimeoToken is an access token I created on vimeo for the app, and I have imported the vimeo api into my project.

```
-(NSString*) getVimeoUrls2 {


    VIMClient *client = [[VIMClient alloc] initWithDefaultBaseURL];
    AFJSONRequestSerializer *serializer= [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];


    NSString *token = kVimeoToken;
   //[serializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [serializer setValue:@"application/vnd.vimeo.*+json; version=3.2" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [serializer setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bearer %@", token]   forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
    client.requestSerializer = serializer;

    __block NSString *str= nil;


    [client requestURI:@"/me" completionBlock:^(VIMServerResponse *response, NSError *error)
    {

        id JSONObject = response.result;
        NSLog(@"JSONObject: %@", JSONObject);
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:JSONObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    }];

return str;
}
```

All I get back is an empty string, any idea what I am doing wrong?
If I change the access token so it is incorrect then I get back an error message {"error":"You must provide a valid authenticated access token."}, so it appears that I get authenticated ok. I have also tried some other endpoints but all of them end up with an empty string.

I have tried two separate approaches, both with the same result...i.e none, or an empty string.

I posted the question on the vimeo forums and got provided these two links:

developer.vimeo.com/api/authentication#single-user
github.com/vimeo/VIMNetworking#lightweight-use

The is the output from the log for the above code is below:

2016-01-09 08:13:26.091 tvOSShortGame[68357:91090409] server start (/me/watched/videos)
2016-01-09 08:13:26.461 tvOSShortGame[68357:91090448] server success 0.370109 sec (/me/watched/videos)

..and if I change the endpoint to /xxx (to force an error)

2016-01-09 08:07:28.826 tvOSShortGame[67829:91039056] server start (/xxx)
2016-01-09 08:07:29.003 tvOSShortGame[67829:91039045] server failure 0.177531 sec (/xxx)
2016-01-09 08:07:29.003 tvOSShortGame[67829:91039460] JSONObject: (null)
2016-01-09 08:07:29.003 tvOSShortGame[67829:91039460] Error: Request failed: not found (404)

Other endpoints get the same result, reports success but there is no JSON object returned.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: What scopes did you select when you generated your token?

Comment: Hi Ryan, I had Public and Private scopes.  I have got it working now with that token, just not through the Vimeo classes.  Found a very useful tool Postman which lets you validate the endpoints and returns the JSON, then gives you the code snippet in multiple languages.

Comment: Consider using the official Vimeo iOS SDK: https://github.com/vimeo/VIMNetworking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got this working by using Postman which I saw on one of the Vimeo forums.  It produces the correct code in multiple languages, and shows the resulting JSON so you can validate your endpoints.

Hope someone finds it useful.

```
//Obj C version

NSDictionary *headers = @{ @"authorization": @"Bearer MY_VIMEO_TOKEN",
                           @"cache-control": @"no-cache",
                           @"postman-token": @"MY_POSTMAN_TOKEN" };

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.vimeo.com/videos/116999999"]
                                                       cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                   timeoutInterval:10.0];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[request setAllHTTPHeaderFields:headers];

NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request
                                            completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                                if (error) {
                                                    NSLog(@"%@", error);
                                                } else {
                                                    NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *) response;
                                                    NSLog(@"%@", httpResponse);
                                                }
                                            }];
[dataTask resume];


//Swift version

    let headers = [
        "authorization": "Bearer MY_VIMEO_TOKEN",
        "cache-control": "no-cache",
    ]

    var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "https://api.vimeo.com/videos/116999999")!,
        cachePolicy: .UseProtocolCachePolicy,
        timeoutInterval: 10.0)
    request.HTTPMethod = "GET"
    request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
    var str = ""
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let dataTask = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        if (error != nil) {
            print(error)
        } else {
            let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse
            str = self.parseJSON(data!)

        }
    })

    dataTask.resume()
```

Comment: I removed your auth tokens from the body of your question, probably not a good idea to post those here.